# Android app for blocking a number that the caller doesn't notice

Tags: android, phone

Is there an Android app for blocking phone calls such that the caller does not notice he/she is being blocked? What I want is the caller keeps ringing for some time, then is disconnected, or he/she hears the message "the party you have called cannot be reached" at once, instead of some special tones. I tried Mr Number but it gives the blocked caller a busy tone a second after normal ringing tone. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult. Some phones even ship with a feature where you simply turn the phone face-down to "silence" a call. While waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to check my list for [Call Blockers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97), one of those might offer something alike (I vaguely remember having seen that but don't remember with which app).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I shall check the page when I have time, but most of them didn't state the specific behavior, it has to be found by installing them. Currently I try to use blank mp3 as ringtone for specific nos. I want to block, but this doesn't work for private nos.

Comment: I've just checked the list (and added some candidates), and couldn't find this mentioned with any. Some have reviews linked to their entries, might have been mentioned in those. I've never had the need for a call blocker, so I didn't try any myself.

Comment: If you identify an app that fits your needs, be welcome to [answer your own question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (nobody could to that better than you then ;) Feel free to include a link to my collection then for alternatives, if it seems suitable to you :) Good luck!